# Am having this error while trying to test my SMTP

Tags: php, laravel, string, symfony, integer

Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Dsn::__construct(): Argument #5 ($port) must be of type ?int, string given, called in /home/eazzylyf/public_html/@core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 186

```
try{

        Mail::to($request->email)->send(new BasicMail([

            'subject' => $request->subject,

            'message' => $request->message

        ]));

    }catch (\Exception $e){

        return redirect()->back()->with(NexelitHelpers::item_delete($e->getMessage()));

    }
```